# Spring Thymeleaf - How to edit(update) a user selected entity(object) via Thymeleaf form?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my application the user is show a list of exam objects and they select one to edit. 
When they click the edit link it brings them to a HTML page where the URL contains that exams ID.

I would like to know how to pass the id of the exam to the controller. 
I'm getting this error: "Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type Long"

I would also like to know how to make existing values appear in the forms text boxses.

HTML allSubjects.html where the user selects a subject to edit: (this all works)

```
    <h4> exams:</h4>
<div th:each="exam : ${subject.exam}"> 
<h4 th:text="${exam.examTitle}"/>
<a th:href="@{/editExam.html(id=${exam.examId})}">Edit Exam</a>
```

Edit exam HTML:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/editExam.html{examId}}"  th:object="${exam}" method="put">


    <table>
        <tr>
        <td> Exam Title:</td>
         <td><input type="text" th:field="*{examTitle}" th:text="${exam.examTitle}"/></td>
    <!--    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('examTitlee')}" th:errors="*{examTitle}">error message</td>  --> 
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td> Exam grade worth </td>
            <td><input th:field="*{examGradeWorth}" /></td>
        <!--    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('examGradeWorth')}" th:errors="*{examGradeWorth}">error message</td> -->
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <td>examGradeAchieved</td>
                <td><input th:field="*{examGradeAchieved}"/></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit">Submit post</button></td>
                </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editExam.html{examId}", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.PUT })
public String editExam(@ModelAttribute("exam") @PathVariable(value = "id")Long examId, @RequestBody Exam exam,Model model, BindingResult result) {

         examRepository.findOne(examId);
            model.addAttribute("examTitle", exam.getExamTitle());
            model.addAttribute("examGradeWorth", exam.getExamGradeWorth());
            model.addAttribute("examGradeAchieved", exam.getExamGradeAchieved());


    exam.setExamTitle(exam.getExamTitle());
         exam.setExamGradeWorth(exam.getExamGradeWorth());
         exam.setExamGradeAchieved(exam.getExamGradeAchieved());

         examRepository.save(exam);

    return "editExam";
}
```

WHen I try to run all the above code just to see if the form displays I get the following error: Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type String